# C++ pointer garbage value only on the first index

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm just a beginner in C++ and i'm having trouble with using pointers. I'm trying to make prim's algorithm.

Skipping index 0, I have index 1~4 pointer instances. 
The 4 pointer values print out just fine within the method.
However, when I print them from main, the index 1 value has garbage and from index 2, the values are just fine.

The correct values are:

```
(v2, v1)
(v4, v2)
(v5, v2)
(v3, v5)
```

however, it comes out like this:

```
(v1606413560, v32767)
(v4, v2)
(v5, v2)
(v3, v5)
```

If i put my value from index 2, and print the pointers from index 2, they come out just fine. Is there something wrong with initiating?

I tried initiating all pointers and variables but still haven't solved it.

These are the classes defined:

```
class Edge
{
public:
    int Vi=0, Vj=0;
    Edge(int vi, int vj)
    {
        Vi=vi;
        Vj=vj;
    }
    Edge()
    {
    }
};

class SetOfEdges
{
public:
    int numOfedge=0;
    Edge* edges;

    SetOfEdges prim(int n, int** W);
    void add(Edge e);

    SetOfEdges()
    {
    }
};
```

The method where the values are printed fine:

```
SetOfEdges SetOfEdges::prim(int n, int** W)
{
    int i, Vnear=0, min;
    Edge e;
    SetOfEdges F = SetOfEdges();

    some codes...

    e = Edge(Vnear,nearest[Vnear]);

    cout<<"(v"<<Vnear <<",v"<<nearest[Vnear]<<")  ";

    F.add(e);
```

The main() where garbage value prints:

```
SetOfEdges soe = SetOfEdges();

soe = soe.prim(numOfnode, W);
cout <<"\n";

for(int i=1; i<=soe.numOfedge;i++)
{
    cout <<"(v"<<soe.edges[i].Vi;
    cout <<", v"<<soe.edges[i].Vj<<")\n";
}
```

the add method:

```
void SetOfEdges::add(Edge e){
    edges[++numOfedge]=e;
}
```

Comment: Why not show us code, rather than post a short story?

Comment: here's my code. it's a little long so I shortened it. Is this okay?

Comment: Where is soe.edges defined?  You know array indexes start at 0, right?

Comment: i added my classes. 
i initialized the array from 0 but i'm trying not to use it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how the **add** method works for your **SetOfEdges** class, but one possible issue is if you correctly allocated memory to F's edges variable. If you aren't allocating the appropriate memory to edges each time you add a new edge, you should be having issues with the values the pointers are pointing too.

Comment: I added the edges by index. Do you mean that the edges needs to be initialized to be allocated?? I allocated them in method prim(), shall i allocate them in main() method?

Comment: You need to initialize the **Edge* edges;** member of the SetOfEdges class so you can actually add items to it.

This could be done in your case in the constructor doing something like:

`edges = new Edge[10];`

This creates an array with 10 Edge elements. You can't do what you have in your **add** function unless you use something like a std::vector<Edge> instead of Edge* for your edges variable. A std::vector acts like a linked list, so you can add new members to it on the fly without knowing the number of elements in advance.

Comment: o i was initializing it the wrong way! I initialized it in the method but i needed it in the SetOfEdges class so that I can use it from the main(). Thank you so much!